# How to build and debug python executable(python interpreter)from source code with Xcode on MacOS

Tags: python, xcode, build

Is it possible to build and debug python executable(python interpreter) from source code with Xcode on MacOS?

I have an iMac which with MacOS 10.13.6 and Xcode 9.4.1 installed. I downloaded source code of python 3.7.1 from www.python.org, and want to build and debug python executable(python interpreter) itself by Xcode. But I can’t find any Xcode project file in python source code, I just found project files for Visual Studio in PCbuild folder.

Or except Xcode, is there any other C/C++ IDE in MacOS can be used for building and debugging Python interpreter?

Can anybody tell me how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use python, Xcode only uses Swift and c++. Try PyCharm on https://www.jetbrains.com/

Comment: PyCharm is an Python IDE for Python programming, what I want is build and debug Python interpreter itself, which is write in C.

Answer (score -1):

No it is not. Xcode is for ObjC and Swift only.

Use PyCharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Comment: PyCharm is an Python IDE for Python programming, what I want is build and debug Python interpreter itself, which is write in C.

Comment: ok, I still don't think Xcode is the tool for you. I would look into CLion, also from Jetbrains then.